# How do I save a textarea in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a program and I made a text area

```
document.write('<textarea id="text1" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>')
```

I need to save the users input to a variable but no matter what I do it wont work. Instead of the users text it, just says `HTML Text Area`

What do I do?

Comment: document.write('<textarea id="text1" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>')   sorry i'm new to this site and my code didn't show above, this is what I need to save

Comment: You should include the command you tried using to get `HTML Text Area`

Comment: It all depends on what you mean by "save"...

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = document.getElementById('yourTextAreaId').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the DOM Element first like `var textarea = document.getElementById('yourTextArea')`

then get the value by `textarea.value`